# Query for a exact string in Zend Lucene PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I am using the Zend Search Lucene. However I am having a little trouble. I wish to query the index for the exact string so page_name IS test123, not any fuzzy match.

Currently I have:

```
$hits = $index->find('page_name:"test123"');
```

And advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before query, use this analyser instead of the default one:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
    new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive()
);
```